# How to sort integer+string value?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

I have `$pallet` and it has values like this:

```
P01  
P02  
P12  
P20  
P05
```

How can I sort these values as:

```
P01  
P02  
P05  
P12  
P20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values always start with 'P' then you could strip out the 'P', convert the rest into a number and then `ORDER BY` that number ASC. Hence:

```
select yourcolumn 
from (
select cast(replace(yourcolumn,'P','') as unsigned) as rank,
yourcolumn from yourtable) t
order by t.rank asc;
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of how sorting alphabetically works:

```
create table pallet (id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
pallet varchar(5));

insert into pallet (pallet) values ('P01');
insert into pallet (pallet) values ('P02');
insert into pallet (pallet) values ('P12');
insert into pallet (pallet) values ('P20');
insert into pallet (pallet) values ('P05');
insert into pallet (pallet) values ('P145');

select * 
from pallet 
order by pallet asc;
```

Result:

```
id  pallet
--  ------
1   P01
2   P02
3   P05
4   P12
5   P145
6   P20
```

Not quite what we wanted!

```
select pallet
from (
select cast(replace(pallet,'P','') as unsigned) as rank,
pallet from pallet) t
order by t.rank asc;
```

Result:

```
id  pallet
--  ------
1   P01
2   P02
3   P05
4   P12
5   P20
6   P145
```

Answer (score 3):

Do they all start with a `P`? If so, you can just `sort($pallet)` or do an `ORDER BY yourcolumnhere ASC` since sorting them in an alphabetical order will be enough.

Comment: Careful. This will only work if the number after the 'P' remains less than 100. A simple `ORDER BY yourcolumnhere ASC` would not work if the value 'P145' was included. Something to bear in mind!

Comment: @TomMac Why this will not work if the number after 'P' big than 100?

Comment: @xdazz It won't work since MySQL will be sorting alphabetically instead of numerically on the values after the 'P'. Hence if you were to add 'P145' into the mix and sorted alphabetically you'd end up with: P01, P02, P05, P12, P145, P20 instead of P01, P02, P05, P12, P20, P145

Comment: True, I made the assumption that the numbers won't exceed 99 because they are zero padded for two digits.